# Decryption with RSACryptoServiceProvider fails

Tags: c#, encryption, key, rsa, biginteger

I want to decrypt a byte array. to do this, I encrypt the data in java with the servers public key. Then I send the data to the c# server. There I want to decrypt with the "RSACryptoServiceProvider" class. I initialize it with:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
rsa.ImportParameters(keyInfo);
```

The "keyInfo" (RSAParameters) variable is initialized with the "modulus" and the "privateKey"

```
keyInfo.Modulus = m.getBytes();
keyInfo.D = d.getBytes();
```

The values for "m" and "d" are hard-coded and from a BigInteger instance from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class). I know hard-coded is bad but currently I can do so.

When I do like this, an exception is thrown "bad data". When I add the public key in

`keyInfo.Exponent = pubExpBytes`

then it passes but an exception is thrown later "Key does not exist" in the method

```
result = rsa.Decrypt(inputBuf, false);
```

and the property "PublicOnly" is true even though I added the key in "keyInfo.D".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you loading your BigInteger object? something like BigInteger bigInt = 235235235235......;?

Comment: I loaded like this: BigInteger m = new BigInteger(modByteArray); but now I'm trying with the xml-string

Comment: In the java code, there is used no default padding. But there are random bytes added. Is this a problem for me or don't I have to consider that when decrypting? How can I decrypt correctly nevertheless? The problem is, I get now a "Bad Data" exception from the "Decrypt"-method. Btw. I can't change the java code

Comment: Without knowing the java code I would try using true when calling the decrypt method.

Comment: Also if the data is being sent to the server it may have been base64 encoded (or other encoding) before being sent up. If that is the case you would have to reverse that before decrypting.

Comment: I see the java code but I'm not allowed to make changes. For padding there are random bytes set (with extra code) but for the cipher it's used "NOPADDING". But I know how long the plain message is without the random padding. How can use this information?

Comment: When you say random bytes set you mean before or after encryption? if before then you can just take a substring if you know the real length and discard the end after decrypting. If after then take a substring using the real length then decrypt that.

Comment: Sorry don't understand fully. before encryption: decrypt with full length then cut to the real length? if after: cut encrypted to real length then decrypt? it's before. Then theoretically the "Decrypt" method should work without any changes before but it gives me a "Bad Data" exception. Hmm I'm gonna search now for a better explanation. Thank you for helping I will come back to check the answer when I solved it and this was true

Comment: Sounds like the encrypted data was encoded in some way by java and then sent to the server. That encoding has to be undone before decryption on the server.

Comment: But the hex dump from the encryted data in java is the same as the received encrypted data in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RSACryptoServiceProvider Private Key is composed of Modulus, Exponent, P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ, and D to be set. It is best to load the key from an xml string like:

```
string xmlKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>2CASUiCNfcCc/Y2gCJwmUPc1VWwsPiMW/4s4EqUWaq29WYQsZj+xUFAlQHLG1VOorjD+UU30Yj3acr4O3b/5iDfsW+2zDc1UB/T+fvzMv6nLNIMJAVST+7GulAbzcmItrdcWi9UN6VWICYatg6QFi2eJIibfwrorzA2v4NXUrja2/OpbePDeIW0NmU2y+U9kl2n0XvQOy87751iRE0bFzRBOzURumh+ZE7pYDXodf50B72bPl/ytKUPzwMOCzOA4qRoROWHwCh5puT8i1FHN8HGykZCZE7s3Enf7UpJ8hp4N4caODQCeBJhISSosN0YTCNIsT76CjyXQwQOMVrDGLQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>81hQqq4N6+ejjtvynaALqwrGX9A7F6xhipYRGUzT4bQ+6n/Z2maADtOw1k2nd1Uz6NmneYGtQkzkqpEgQvJ89Ds0m/ndDqySKpV+qWJzW8QeLmm7rqhcVmjMqaTYYfb2nJj0C7a9ixf8JsKKV5I6Q4E8iZNDJQkD0Ap1mXwEXX8=</P><Q>411gemkRFxg/mu51aHk6F/D/kfgBZHV7pGohzgJ3LFFfDxsLviWeLLWcLna9nV9YZpP7QaNchIHOiRq63I/JPn9E+gieTWpAFTLOVhNRdchdI8sE/OUTE7Q8CAeNHlZWqv6DZpUxPBWNFaqO2zuq2t104CAItwFfp+599mkgilM=</Q><DP>OA2Hx0kAe+6HhkizwgszpNp+h2N3uSRD86BNn/5KcBsMwwdgLyadKM0qVrLceGhv5Jr+MMbmGfeMVJ3JSKKCld9tZuBPQyoNITH+UxYSbHjoWtiQGtM9McpCGnGWRjqU4813qZsWXgvQUT1OkI1mTlZek3IQbV9+OVWvcQNYHhE=</DP><DQ>a1ehfglurSWgmefs/GcHe1gngOXC2ofw2N3WmelmFEFSjNIrCBnAhME1PGaI/OyP0tYYsJOM0W5rcSVyhUFJNL1ndlhtTIVWPevfqJm0QtRWzNhDwZXxHMNh+DSAdosyncZNiTf0p7ZRBqKgkXapIm2diVb2Zlg6rhEV3Ski2Ms=</DQ><InverseQ>XQJzVm1AFLJkbsrGb19MUOauBiDzlssX8VXT3A9gB0zsVclhgWpZMMKia1iAgrTg5nqhy2PIqvBJ9Vu3GGO6IP0lmLXwI83cOhso7AIz9dAknI4xR4LlLKtnbmw6ozwWMzxx+5fsKDbnTB5wiAIepZDXARdm9bmr791mXJXZQWA=</InverseQ><D>YbeygOaOAscVVED2FB6B5oa3Ww2jPV8BNX59VlTFO2udmr07k+mFYrIx/Z9HjkmakVO+kQVFkyuzOsD7GMEFclUSrYfeNsXZEhXwAXuMmbYMFgyPBEZ4+Eqgi/ZOmS+RxrFi1Mt6VD8jWGdHyabeCOdBpircbf9d8Q9ZL7eOx0tKAnn4QCcxxErDsRbAYLWKF8SClSGgEu2sfvBU/zMvJ2Lm6XTepItyfzWp+/eiN6ovg6OjuUtg4p7i8jEWP7M/LmLqAusjBtSve+0HF+d38DyD2kL6+ocIPwpXyuY5DjMazJtTCarmr+ryKkiUdFRtmwRf6XufFZSHrsEnmzEp0w==</D></RSAKeyValue>"
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(xmlKey);
byte[] decryptedData = rsa.Decrypt(inputBuf, false);
```

You can see that each of the xml tags in the string account for each component of the key.

A public key consists of just a Modulus and an Exponent. Adding all the other components makes the key private. The values you set are missing some of the private components and is why PublicOnly is true. Just to avoid confusion the Public key is what encrypts data and the private key is the only way to decrypt it, which you would be using in your C# server code.

(The key in this example is 2048 just use 1024 for your use)

Comment: this helped me thx. why are the private exponent with modulus not enough? the decrypt function is "m = c^d (mod n)" so these two parameters should be enough? is it for performance reason?

Comment: Yes I remember that as the reason, decryption and signing are drastically sped up using the extra components and is how .Net's implementation works. I remember reading something on it but can not remember where.